# d-ary heap in C

Tags: c, heap, priority-queue

Now I have this `d`-ary heap data structure. Note that for `d = 2` this is a binary heap. The client programmer specifies the value of `d` when constructing the heap. See what I have:

**heap.h**:

```
#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef struct heap_t heap_t;

    /***************************************************************************
    * Allocates a new, empty heap of degree 'degree'.                          *
    ***************************************************************************/  
    heap_t* heap_t_alloc(size_t degree,
                         size_t initial_capacity,
                         float load_factor,
                         size_t (*p_hash_function)(void*),
                         bool (*p_equals_function)(void*, void*),
                         int (*p_priority_compare_function)(void*, void*));

    /***************************************************************************
    * Adds a new element and its priority to the heap only if it is not        *
    * already present.                                                         *
    ***************************************************************************/  
    bool heap_t_add(heap_t* p_heap, void* p_element, void* p_priority);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Attempts to assign a higher priority to the 'element'. Return true only  *       
    * if the structure of the heap changed due to this call.                   * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    bool heap_t_decrease_key(heap_t* p_heap, void* p_element, void* p_priority);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Return true only if 'p_element' is in the heap.                          * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    bool heap_t_contains_key(heap_t* p_heap, void* p_element);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Removes the highest priority element and returns it.                     * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    void* heap_t_extract_min(heap_t* p_heap);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the highest priority element without removing it.                * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    void* heap_t_min(heap_t* p_heap);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Returns the size of this heap.                                           * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    int heap_t_size(heap_t* p_heap);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Drops all the contents of the heap. Only internal structures are         *
    * deallocated; the user is responsible for memory-managing the contents.   * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    void heap_t_clear(heap_t* p_heap);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Checks that the heap maintains the min-heap property.                    *
    ***************************************************************************/  
    bool heap_t_is_healthy(heap_t* p_heap);

    /***************************************************************************
    * Deallocates the entire heap with its internal structures. The client     *
    * programmer must, however, memory-manage the contents.                    * 
    ***************************************************************************/  
    void heap_t_free(heap_t* p_heap);

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  /* HEAP_H */
```

**heap.c**:

```
#include "heap.h"
#include "unordered_map.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct heap_node_t {
    void*  p_element;
    void*  p_priority;
    size_t index;
} heap_node_t;

typedef struct heap_t {
    unordered_map_t* p_node_map;
    heap_node_t**    p_table;
    size_t         (*p_hash_function)(void*);
    bool           (*p_equals_function)(void*, void*);
    int            (*p_key_compare_function)(void*, void*);
    size_t           size;
    size_t           capacity;
    size_t           degree;
    size_t*          p_indices;
} heap_t;

static heap_node_t* heap_node_t_alloc(void* p_element, void* p_priority) 
{
    heap_node_t* p_ret = malloc(sizeof(*p_ret));

    if (!p_ret) return NULL;

    p_ret->p_element = p_element;
    p_ret->p_priority = p_priority;

    return p_ret;
}

static const size_t MINIMUM_CAPACITY = 16;

static int fix_degree(size_t degree) 
{
    return degree < 2 ? 2 : degree;
}

static size_t fix_initial_capacity(size_t initial_capacity) 
{
    return initial_capacity < MINIMUM_CAPACITY ? 
        MINIMUM_CAPACITY : 
        initial_capacity;
}

heap_t* heap_t_alloc(size_t degree,
                     size_t initial_capacity,
                     float load_factor,
                     size_t (*p_hash_function)(void*),
                     bool (*p_equals_function)(void*, void*),
                     int (*p_priority_compare_function)(void*, void*))
{
    heap_t* p_ret;
    unordered_map_t* p_map;

    if (!p_hash_function)        return NULL;
    if (!p_equals_function)      return NULL;
    if (!p_priority_compare_function) return NULL;

    p_ret = malloc(sizeof(*p_ret));

    if (!p_ret) return NULL;

    p_map = unordered_map_t_alloc(initial_capacity,
                                  load_factor,
                                  p_hash_function,
                                  p_equals_function);

    if (!p_map) 
    {
        free(p_ret);
        return NULL;
    }

    degree = fix_degree(degree);
    initial_capacity = fix_initial_capacity(initial_capacity);

    p_ret->p_table = malloc(sizeof(heap_node_t*) * initial_capacity);

    if (!p_ret->p_table) 
    {
        unordered_map_t_free(p_map);
        free(p_ret);
        return NULL;
    }

    p_ret->p_indices = malloc(sizeof(size_t) * degree);

    if (!p_ret->p_indices) 
    {
        unordered_map_t_free(p_map);
        free(p_ret->p_table);
        free(p_ret);
        return NULL;
    }

    p_ret->p_node_map             = p_map;
    p_ret->capacity               = initial_capacity;
    p_ret->size                   = 0;
    p_ret->degree                 = degree;
    p_ret->p_hash_function        = p_hash_function;
    p_ret->p_equals_function      = p_equals_function;
    p_ret->p_key_compare_function = p_priority_compare_function;

    return p_ret;
}

static size_t get_parent_index(heap_t* p_heap, size_t child_index)
{
    return (child_index - 1) / p_heap->degree;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Sifts up the node until the minimum heap property is restored.               * 
*******************************************************************************/
static void sift_up(heap_t* p_heap, size_t index)
{
    size_t parent_index;
    heap_node_t* p_target_node;
    heap_node_t* p_parent_node;

    if (index == 0) return;

    parent_index = get_parent_index(p_heap, index);
    p_target_node = p_heap->p_table[index];

    for (;;) 
    {
        p_parent_node = p_heap->p_table[parent_index];

        if (p_heap->p_key_compare_function(p_parent_node->p_priority,
                                           p_target_node->p_priority) > 0)
        {
            p_heap->p_table[index] = p_parent_node;
            p_parent_node->index = index;
            index = parent_index;
            parent_index = get_parent_index(p_heap, index);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        if (index == 0) break;
    }

    p_heap->p_table[index] = p_target_node;
    p_target_node->index = index;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Loads the indices of child nodes relative to the node with index 'index'.    * 
*******************************************************************************/
static void compute_children_indices(heap_t* p_heap, size_t index)
{
    size_t degree = p_heap->degree;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < degree; ++i)
    {
        p_heap->p_indices[i] = degree * index + i + 1;

        if (p_heap->p_indices[i] >= p_heap->size)
        {
            p_heap->p_indices[i] = (size_t) -1;
            return;
        }
    }
}

bool heap_t_is_healthy(heap_t* p_heap)
{
    size_t i;
    size_t j;
    size_t child_index;

    if (!p_heap) return false;

    for (i = 0; i < p_heap->size; ++i) 
    {
        /* Check that all the children of the current node has priorities no
           less than the node itself. */
        compute_children_indices(p_heap, i);

        for (j = 0; j < p_heap->degree; ++j) 
        {
            child_index = p_heap->p_indices[j];

            if (child_index != (size_t) -1)
            {
                if (p_heap->
                        p_key_compare_function(
                            p_heap->p_table[i]->p_priority, 
                            p_heap->p_table[child_index]->p_priority) > 0)
                {
                    printf("SHIT, %d > %d\n", p_heap->p_table[i]->p_priority, p_heap->p_table[child_index]->p_priority);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Sifts down the node at the root to location that maintains the minimum heap  *
* property.                                                                    *  
*******************************************************************************/
static void sift_down_root(heap_t* p_heap) 
{
    heap_node_t* p_target = p_heap->p_table[0];
    void* p_priority = p_target->p_priority;
    void* p_min_child_priority;
    void* p_tentative_priority;
    size_t min_child_index;
    size_t i;
    size_t degree = p_heap->degree;
    size_t index = 0;

    for (;;) 
    {
        p_min_child_priority = p_priority;
        min_child_index = -1; /* Very large value to denote "no children". */
        compute_children_indices(p_heap, index);

        for (i = 0; i < degree; ++i) 
        {
            if (p_heap->p_indices[i] == (size_t) -1)
            {
                break;
            }

            p_tentative_priority = p_heap->p_table[p_heap->p_indices[i]]
                                         ->p_priority;

            if (p_heap->p_key_compare_function(p_min_child_priority,
                                               p_tentative_priority) > 0)
            {
                p_min_child_priority = p_tentative_priority;
                min_child_index = p_heap->p_indices[i];
            }
        }

        if (min_child_index == (size_t) -1)
        {
            p_heap->p_table[index] = p_target;
            p_target->index = index;
            return;
        }

        p_heap->p_table[index] = p_heap->p_table[min_child_index];
        p_heap->p_table[index]->index = index;

        index = min_child_index;
    }
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Makes sure that the heap has more room for new elements.                     *
*******************************************************************************/  
static bool ensure_capacity_before_add(heap_t* p_heap) 
{
    heap_node_t** p_new_table;
    size_t        new_capacity;
    size_t        i;
    if (p_heap->size < p_heap->capacity) 
        return true;

    new_capacity = 3 * p_heap->capacity / 2;
    p_new_table  = malloc(sizeof(heap_node_t*) * new_capacity);

    if (!p_new_table) return false;

    for (i = 0; i < p_heap->size; ++i)
    {
        p_new_table[i] = p_heap->p_table[i];
    }

    free(p_heap->p_table);
    p_heap->p_table  = p_new_table;
    p_heap->capacity = new_capacity;
    return true;
}

bool heap_t_add(heap_t* p_heap, void* p_element, void* p_priority)
{
    heap_node_t* p_node;

    if (!p_heap) return false;

    /* Already in the heap? */
    if (unordered_map_t_contains_key(p_heap->p_node_map, p_element)) 
        return false; 

    p_node = heap_node_t_alloc(p_element, p_priority);

    if (!p_node) return false;

    if (!ensure_capacity_before_add(p_heap)) 
        return false;

    p_node->index = p_heap->size;
    p_heap->p_table[p_heap->size] = p_node;
    unordered_map_t_put(p_heap->p_node_map, p_element, p_node);
    sift_up(p_heap, p_heap->size);
    p_heap->size++;
    return true;
}

bool heap_t_decrease_key(heap_t* p_heap, void* p_element, void* p_priority)
{
    heap_node_t* p_node;

    if (!p_heap) return false;

    if (!unordered_map_t_contains_key(p_heap->p_node_map, p_element)) 
        return false;

    p_node = unordered_map_t_get(p_heap->p_node_map, p_element);

    if (p_heap->p_key_compare_function(p_priority, p_node->p_priority) < 0)
    {
        p_node->p_priority = p_priority;
        sift_up(p_heap, p_node->index);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool heap_t_contains_key(heap_t* p_heap, void* p_element)
{
    if (!p_heap) return false;

    return unordered_map_t_contains_key(p_heap->p_node_map, p_element);
}

void* heap_t_extract_min(heap_t* p_heap)
{
    void* p_ret;
    heap_node_t* p_node;

    if (!p_heap)           return NULL;
    if (p_heap->size == 0) return NULL;

    p_node = p_heap->p_table[0];
    p_ret = p_node->p_element;
    p_heap->size--;
    p_heap->p_table[0] = p_heap->p_table[p_heap->size];
    unordered_map_t_remove(p_heap->p_node_map, p_ret);
    sift_down_root(p_heap);
    free(p_node);
    return p_ret;
}

void* heap_t_min(heap_t* p_heap)
{
    if (!p_heap)           return NULL;
    if (p_heap->size == 0) return NULL;
    return p_heap->p_table[0]->p_element;
}

int heap_t_size(heap_t* p_heap)
{
    return p_heap ? p_heap->size : -1;
}

void heap_t_clear(heap_t* p_heap)
{
    size_t i;

    if (!p_heap) return;

    unordered_map_t_clear(p_heap->p_node_map);

    for (i = 0; i < p_heap->size; ++i)
    {
        free(p_heap->p_table[i]);
    }
}

void heap_t_free(heap_t* p_heap) 
{
    if (!p_heap) return;

    heap_t_clear(p_heap);
    unordered_map_t_free(p_heap->p_node_map);
    free(p_heap->p_indices);
    free(p_heap->p_table);
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/coderodde/coderodde.c.utils) you can find everything else needed for running the demonstration.

Now, how can I improve the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Repeated search

In the `decrease_key()` function, you search twice for an entry, once to see if it exists, and a second time to retrieve the node:

> ```
> if (!unordered_map_t_contains_key(p_heap->p_node_map, p_element)) 
>     return false;
>
> p_node = unordered_map_t_get(p_heap->p_node_map, p_element);
> ```

You can omit the first search and just get the node.  If the node is `NULL`, then you know it didn't exist.

## Minor issue

In your `add()` function, you allocate a node and then you ensure capacity for the new node, like this:

> ```
> p_node = heap_node_t_alloc(p_element, p_priority);
>
> if (!p_node) return false;
>
> if (!ensure_capacity_before_add(p_heap)) 
>     return false;
> ```

If the node allocation succeeds but the ensure capacity fails, you will have leaked the node allocation.  I feel like this is a pretty minor issue because if the ensure capacity fails, you will be running out of memory and your program will probably exit soon.

I didn't really see any other problems, although I didn't have as much time to look at this as with your previous two questions.

## Four letter words in the code

I noticed this in your health function:

> ```
>     printf("SHIT, %d > %d\n", ...
> ```

While this is fine for your own debugging purposes, it's good to get in a habit of keeping your source code sanitized.  This kind of stuff happens a lot at companies and it's embarrassing for them when their source code is released and it contains a whole bunch of snarky comments and four letter words and such.

Comment: @coderodde Yeah sorry I did not have much time to look at this.  But from what I did see, there weren't many issues.  I'll go ahead and list another small issue I found.  I didn't think it was worth mentioning before.